# Can't pull or push code from bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

the thing is, suddenly git stoped working.. I can't push or pull code from bitbucket, I cant clone the repos either..

```
$ git pull origin master
error: Failed connect to bitbucket.org:443; Operation now in progress while accessing https://username@bitbucket.org/username/username.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed


$ git push origin master
error: Failed connect to bitbucket.org:443; Operation now in progress while accessing https://username@bitbucket.org/username/username.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I can however clone the repos from github

```
$ git clone https://github.com/rails/rails.git
Cloning into 'rails'...
remote: Counting objects: 374775, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (100606/100606), done.
remote: Total 374775 (delta 288080), reused 356367 (delta 270840)
Receiving objects: 100% (374775/374775), 56.24 MiB | 4.47 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (288080/288080), done.
```

iptables

```
$ sudo iptables -L -n
[sudo] password for user:
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

also I have run sudo ufw disable...

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be a side-effect of the recent incident seen in the [BitBucket status history](http://status.bitbucket.org/):

> 22:52 UTC We're investigating an issue with the site affecting all users. We'll keep you posted as we know more.
>   23:23 UTC The problem appears to be a networking issue and we're working to resolve it as soon as possible.

That, or your proxy has changed its policies, and now block bitbucket, but not github (but I doubt that.)
This error message [has been seen when no proxy is defined](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Git_Tips#Git_https_via_github_and_behind_proxy).

If you have registered a public ssh key, you can try if the ssh url work better.

```
ssh://git@bitbucket.org:username/repo.git
```

Comment: I added the proxy, and things got rolling.. I guess hosting company did change something.. then again that's a VPS with private IP.. not sure whats going on.. Thanks m8.

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue.

I tried to update git by ppa, Reset .gitconfig,i checked github repo is getting clone but not bitbucket, i unset http and https proxy, restarted my network services(type in terminal - 'my network services'), changed the network that my laptop was connected. But none of this didn't work for me.

i got fixed by adding below line to hosts(/etc/hosts) file

> 104.192.143.2 bitbucket.org

Another solutions i didn't tried are

using proxy for cloning git, Connecting to Bitbucket using ssh through proxy